# Lower bounds on simple hash table operations?

Tags: ds.data-structures, lower-bounds

There are a variety of hash tables that support worst-case O(1)-time lookups and deletions and expected O(1)-time lookups. Is there a known lower-bound on hashing that says that there cannot be a hash table with (possibly amortized) worst-case O(1) lookups, insertions, and deletions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best known lower bounds are discussed in [Thorup's "Mihai Pǎtraşcu: Obituary and Open Problems"](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2447737), and none preclude deterministic amortized constant-time operations.